# Flutter need to add shadow on image

Tags: flutter

I need to add shadow in my image. Just on image not the other container i try but its not showing shadow

Here is my code

```
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
  child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _places.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, int index) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(_places[index]['name'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    width: 200,
                    child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/500place.jpg')),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.favorite_border, size: 20),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text(
                      _places[index]['where'],
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ),

            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
);
```

[image]

As you see the result of the output screen I need to show the light shadow on image only i added the box shadow in container but its not working on image only

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with a `Card`..that will give you the `elevation`(shadow)..

You can do it like this..

```
Card(
child: Container(),
elevation: 20.0, // give it according to your requirement
),
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single shadow line

```
  Card(
    child: Container(
           width: double.infinity,
           height: 1,
         ),
     elevation: 1.0, // give it according to your requirement
   )
```